# How to make validation auto scroll to first error on top smoothly but not jumping to the first invalid error?

Tags: jquery, autoscroll

What I have try is this but it doesn't work the scroll still jump up to the invalid error validation. Please help me with this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0},800);
    return false;
  });
});
```

I have try many example in google but all can't seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem :

1. You want to use smooth scroll with on validation check
2. You want to add focus on first invalid error field

> Solution : you need to use jquery animate scrolltop callback function,
>   it will fire only after completing animation.

Check below example :

```js
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800
        , function(){
            if ($('#tb1').val() == '') { $('#tb1').focus(); return; }
            if ($('#tb2').val() == '') { $('#tb2').focus(); return; }
            if ($('#country').val() == '--select country--') { $('#country').focus(); return; }
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Name : <br />
<input type="text" id="tb1" required />
<br />

Age :<br />
<input type="text" id="tb2"  required />
<br />

Country :<br />
<select id="country">
<option>--select country--</option>
<option>India</option>
<option>USA</option>
<option>UK</option>
<option>China</option>
</select>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<button id="submit">Click here!</button>
```

Comment: just want to ask does it work for select option validate too??

Comment: @stephanielou, `<select>` option applied in above example, please check.